# Slow Buttons with Custom Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-keyboard-extension

We made a custom keyboard and uploaded to the App Store, the design and the keyboard works fine. However we get a lot 1-star reviews due to slowness of the buttons. The question is. Is there a way to speed `UIButtons` up?

UIControl's `touchUpInside` works once the user release their finger off the button, in some cases people write so fast and `touchUpInside` isn't the "Fast" way do do it

`TouchDown` will fire before `TouchUpInside` because touch down is the action of your finger touching down on the phone.

Please advice on this, What and Which way do you generally prefer for a production keyboard

This is my current method of handling a tap: which's too slow!

```
func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
       self.textDocumentProxy.insert("B")
}
```

Comment: Apple’s default keyboard registers a key on touch up. But, on the iPhone, if a second key is pressed while the first is down, then the first key is registered then and doesn’t wait for its touch up. This keeps the input in the touch down order. Does your keyboard work this way?

Comment: Yes, @vacawama.

Comment: Bare in mind that the pressed key should register the previous one first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed of *TouchDown* vs. *TouchUpInside* isn't really the issue.  The problem comes when users are typing with both thumbs and the key strokes are interpreted in the wrong order.

Apple’s default keyboard registers a key on touch up. But, on the iPhone, if a second key is pressed while the first is down, then the first key is registered then and doesn’t wait for its touch up. This keeps the input in the touch down order (for two thumb typing), but still reflects the touch up behavior.

To implement this, you need to observe both *TouchDown* and *TouchUpInside* events.

Here is one way you could do it.  Create a property called `pendingButton` to track the last button pressed down, and process that button either when it is let up or another button is pressed down.

You'll need to connect `buttonDown` to *TouchDown* events and `buttonUp` to *TouchUpInside* events.

```
// last button pressed down
var pendingButton: String?

// connect button TouchDown events here    
@IBAction func buttonDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // If we already have a pending button, process it before storing
    // the next one
    if let pending = self.pendingButton {
        self.textDocumentProxy.insert(pending)
    }
    self.pendingButton = sender.currentTitle
}

// connect button TouchUpInside events here   
@IBAction func buttonUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // If the button being let up is the latest pending button,
    // then process it, otherwise ignore it
    if sender.currentTitle == self.pendingButton {
        self.textDocumentProxy.insert(self.currentTitle!)
        self.pendingButton = nil
    }
}
```

**Note:**  You might also want to consider carefully other events such as *TouchUpOutside*.  That should probably be connected to `buttonUp` as well depending on the desired behavior of your keyboard.

If instead, dragging outside of a button cancels the button, then you should implement a function to observe *TouchDragExit* and then cancel the pending button if that is the pending button.

```
// connect button TouchDragExit events here
@IBAction func dragExit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentTitle == self.pendingButton {
        self.pendingButton = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

simplest way to speed up use dispatch queue

```swift
     DispatchQueue.main.async { 
       self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(self.currentTitle!)}
```

I did this and got speed as like as original keyboard